# is "unzip" the same as "extract"?

Tags: windows-7, zip

I've downloaded some industry software to my desktop there is a pdf with it that says I should unzip the folder (its a compressed zipped folder). When I night click it I get the option to "extract" but not to "unzip". Is this the same thing? I've tried it and the software still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong or is the software faulty in some other way?

Comment: "Unzipping" a RAR file sounds a bit heretical...

Comment: How about "uncompress", "decompress" or "unpack", that way no one is offended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in this context (processing a file with `.zip` extension) they mean the same thing: *Unzip* is to *extract* like *Kleenex* to *tissue*: one mostly refers to a specific brand, the other is the generic term.

You have a `.zip` file that is a bundle of other files. By *unzipping*, or *extracting*, you're "opening the bundle" and get the contained files.

*Extracting* is a more general term, since there are many different kinds of these archives, not just `.zip` files, like `.tar` or `.rar` files. Consequently, terms like *untar* or *unrar* are used for those.